# Does quantum gravity entail that spacetime is emergent?

Tags: spacetime, quantum-gravity

It is being said by some people, that quantum gravity entails that spacetime is an emergent phenomenon, and thus that the immaterial gives rise to the material. Is this what quantum graivty entails, or is this a bastardization of quantum gravity?

Further, is it true what Lee Smolin says that in order to unify General Relativity and Quantum Mechanics, we are going to have to give up the notion that spacetime is the framework in which things occur.

And also, Dr. Donald Hoffman says that even if Loop Quantum Gravity is wrong and String theory is wrong, spacetime is still discrete, and that means it's pixelized. Does discrete space mean something is pixelized?

Comment: Related though not exactly a duplicate: [Could gravity be an emergent property of nature?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1216/)