# momentum conservation in particle-antiparticle creation

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, pair-production

It's understood that the PRESENCE of a heavy nucleus is necessary for conservation of linear momentum in pair creation. What I can't understand is why it must occur in ADJACENCY of the nucleus. Is there something I'm neglecting?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13513/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Being "near by" means that there is (unavoidably) an interaction between them.

The problem is no longer
$$ \gamma \to e^+ + e^- \,,$$
but
$$ \gamma + A \to e^+ + e^- + A\,,$$
(here $A$ represents the spectator nucleus) and there is now a way to share out the energy and momentum. The interaction is generally thought of as mediated by the electromagnetic interaction.