# Calculation of the angle in pair production

Tags: particle-physics

Related to [Angle in pair production](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/407890/angle-in-pair-production), how can I calculate what is the angle in which two photons are emitted in pair production? I found that the angle should be 0.8 MeV/E but I do not have any idea where this number is coming from...

Would that also apply to the calculation of the angle of two photons emitted in a $\pi^0$ decay?

Comment: Pair production is usually used for the case where two fermions of opposite charge are created from a photon. Photon pairs of course can occur in decays of bosons (such as $\pi^0$ or positronium). The angle between the photons is not uniquely determined, however, in the lab frame (it is 180° in the centre of mass frame due to conservation of momentum), but depends on the relative orientation of the boost and the emission direction of the photons. You can of course derive the distribution of angles. $0.8 MeV/E$ does not look like an angle, by the way, since it is not restricted to $[0, 2\pi]$.

Comment: ($0.8 MeV/E$ might be correct in the limit of high energies).