# Why does graviton generated in a single point lead to disastrous results?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-gravity

In the book The Elegant Universe

Author is talking about particle-antiparticle collision and annihilation in terms of strings. My previous [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/358442/particle-anti-particle-annihilation/).

Now,

> When the force involved in the interaction is the graviton instead of photon-this complete packing of the force's punch into a single point leads to disastrous results, such as the infinite answers we alluded to earlier.

I don't understand this statement. Why graviton generated in a single point leads to absurd results?

Comment: Let me answer both your previous question and the new one, and possibly the forthcoming ones, in a single comment: "The Elegant Universe" is a bad book. Stop reading it. Learn basic physics, and then learn advanced physics. I'll all make sense eventually. Good luck.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3901/