# Photon "stuck" on the event horizon of a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, photons, event-horizon

According to what I've read on special relativity, $c$ is the speed limit for every object in the universe, and according to Einstein, an object's speed through the three spatial dimensions plus its speed through the fourth temporal dimension always sums to $c$.

I once watched a video demonstrating what it would be like to fall into a black hole. At one point the author stated that if a photon was emitted directly away from the singularity and at a distance equal to the Schwarzschild radius, the photon would hover there for eternity.

My question is based on these assumptions so please let me know if either is incorrect.

With its motion through the spatial dimensions halted, will the photon in question not experience time at roughly the same rate we do? Will it decay?

Answer (score 7):

First, a couple things:

- photons do not "experience" time in general, precisely because they always travel at $c$.
- because of the above point, photons do not decay, either.

To better visualize what's happening, consider that the event horizon is a place where *spacetime itself* is "falling" into the black hole at the speed of light.  So, if you emit a photon precisely as you pass the event horizon, the photon's physical motion through space would be exactly counteracted by the spacetime curvature at the horizon, and it would effectively "hover" at that location.

However, the way that this photon would be *observed* is very different for different observers:

The *in-falling* observer, who emits the photon just as she passes the event horizon, will believe that the photon is traveling away from her (at $c$, as usual).

However, a *distant* observer (far from the black hole) will never see the photon at all. Or rather, to the distant observer, the photon will appear to be infinitely redshifted.

An observer who falls into the black hole *after* the first in-falling observer still has a chance to observe the photon (not redshifted).

But more practically speaking, this kind of "equilibrium" would be highly unstable (the photon would not be able to "hover" for very long). This is because the black hole's Schwarzschild radius is always changing slightly, whether it's due to the black hole absorbing CMB radiation, or emitting Hawking radiation.  So, the photon will eventually either escape, or be dragged deeper into the black hole.

Comment: Is it necessarily true that massless particles don't decay?  That seems wrong to me, though I have to invoke non-free states like gluons to come up with an obvious counterexample.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: I don't think gluons can be used as counter example - the decaying ones should be off mass-shell...

Comment: @Christoph: Yeah, and they're not physical states anyway.

Comment: @Jerry I think it is necessarily true, because if a massless particle (on shell) were to decay, the products would necessarily have a rest frame, in which conservation of momentum would have been violated. The only exception AFAIK is collinear branching, but I wouldn't consider that to be a decay process.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: for what it's worth, the fact that massless particles cannot decay makes sense from a classical (relativistic) point of view: quantum-mechanical decay is random and has a finite probability to happen *in a certain time interval*; now, think about proper time for massless particles...

Comment: @Christoph: the energy of the massless particle gives you a time scale in any frame.  That the decay time would be covariant isn't a huge issue.  And you could get away from David Z's objection by making sure that the decay products had no common rest frame.  It's probably right that these processes are forbidden, but it's not OBVIOUSLY so.

Comment: @Christoph: A decaying particle is not off-shell, it is on-shell, but with imaginary mass.

Comment: @FredericBrünner: I did not talk about arbitrary particles - or do you have a particular process involving on-shell decaying gluons in mind?

Comment: @Christoph: Me neither, I was talking about gluons in the same context as you. A decaying gluon must be on-shell, a virtual (off-shell) gluon is not really a particle.

Comment: There is no general reason why massless particles can't decay. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12488/decay-of-massless-particles

Comment: Dmitry, is it kind of expansion but opposite? I.e. is about a kind of shrinking a scale factor? How the metric outside and inside are connected ( if they have to). I suppose the interior metric is the Schwarzchild one. I try to grasp a sense of common statement here and there at least to exclude what is wrong or falsely friendly.