# Are black holes black?

Tags: general-relativity, visible-light, black-holes, event-horizon

GR was formulated before atomic clocks and radio signals between earth and space probes allowed actual measurements to be made.

Atomic clocks count a beat frequency, but the frequency of emitted photons is actually a measure of the energy levels within an atom. As an atomic clock is lowered doing work, its slowed rate is proof that the energy to do that work came from the energy $E = mc^2$ of its matter. This leads to a simple differential equation $c^2 dm = m d\Phi$ with solution $m = m_0 e^{\Phi/c^2}$

Thus gravitational potential has a physical effect on matter and by consideration of the effect on the time delay on radio signals deduce that the lengths of rulers and the rate of clocks are affected by factors of $e^{\Phi/c^2}.$

GR coincides with this in the weak field approximation which equates to the first two terms of the exponential series. Correcting our understanding of gravity by replacing the weak field approximation with exponential function, we avoid the concepts of event horizons and singularities.

So bearing the above in mind, are black holes hiding behind even horizons, or is their light simply red shifted too far to detect?

Comment: From who's point of view?

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question @JohnRennie but possibly a duplicate of a question about the formation of black holes. The question here is about the existence or not of an event horizon (which is assumed in your other answer).

Comment: @RobJeffries hmm, OK, I'm not sure I agree but I have reopened the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a black hole black?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28297/)

Comment: "So bearing the above in mind, are black holes hiding behind even horizons, or is their light simply red shifted too far to detect?" This question might be answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109583/) by John Rennie.

Comment: My question was posed to give astronomers the opportunity to consider the possibility that the Schwarzschild metric might be wrong. The supposed event horizon is an artefact of the metric. I am suggesting that the two pieces of experimental evidence now make it possible to determine the real metric to be ds^2 = e^(2.Phi/c^2)(dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 + c^2.dt^2).  Or in more simple terms, rulers contract and clocks slow by factors of e^(Phi/c^2)

Comment: Could you please clarify what two pieces of evidence you are referring to? Also, there are three problems with your exponential metric. One is that the sign of $dt$ must be the opposite from the spatial components (a typo perhaps?). The other is that distances near a black hole do not contract, but expand. So the sign in your exponent should be reversed for the spatial components (assuming $\Phi<0$). Finally, $\Phi$ in your metric is not defined. $\Phi$ depends on the metric, but your metric depends on $\Phi$ creating a circular reference and thus undefined.

Comment: I thought the experimental evidence was common knowledge. A quick google produced two examples.
NIST article on effect of altitude: nist-pair-aluminum-atomic-clocks-reveal-einsteins-relativity-personal-scale

Viking relativity experiment - Verification of signal retardation by solar gravity
Authors: Reasenberg, R. D., Shapiro, I. I., MacNeil, P. E., Goldstein, R. B., Breidenthal, J. C., 
Brenkle, J. P., , 
Journal: Astrophysical Journal, Part 2 - Letters to the Editor, vol. 234, Dec. 15, 1979, p. L219-L221.
Bibliographic Code: 1979ApJ...234L.219R

Comment: I agree with you about the sign of the dt term. That was a slip. Phi = -G*M/ r. Sorry, but I think in terms of real physical effects on rulers and clocks.
As I read the Schwarzschild metric, vertical rulers are contracted, but horizontal rulers are unaffected. I consider this wrong.

Comment: I think your comment about lengths being greater is a matter semantics. If at some distance from a white draw star, the effect of gravitational potential causes the speed of light to be reduced by a factor of 0.81, in 100 nanoseconds it will travel 81ft, but measuring that with a ruler that is 0.9ft long gives 90 ft. Timing it with a clock that runs slow gives 90 seconds and the locally measured speed of light is 1 ft/nanosecond. There is a sense in which the 81ft of Euclidian space has become 90 of locally measured space.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is $dE=c^2 dm$ (from $E=mc^2$) combined with $dE=m\,d\Phi$ (from $E=\Phi m$) giving

$$c^2 dm=m\,d\Phi$$

Or

$$\dfrac{dm}{m}=\dfrac{d\Phi}{c^2}$$

That solves

$$m = m_0 e^{\frac{\Phi}{c^2}}\tag{1}$$

However, you have overlooked the fact that $m=m(\Phi)$, thus
$dE=m\,d\Phi{\color{red}{+\Phi\,dm}}$. This gives

$$c^2 dm=m\,d\Phi+\Phi\,dm$$

Or

$$\dfrac{dm}{m}=\dfrac{d\Phi}{c^2-\Phi}$$

Solving

$$m=\dfrac{m_o}{1-\dfrac{\Phi}{c^2}}\tag{2}$$

Note that the first two terms of the Taylor series are the same for $(1)$ and $(2)$ referring to the Newtonian gravity, but not General Relativity.

None of this has to do with the existence of the event horizon, because $\Phi(r)$ is not defined above. Its definition in relativity comes from time dilation. For example, in the Schwarzchild solution with no motion

$$\dfrac{d\tau}{dt}=\sqrt{1-\dfrac{r_{\text{s}}}{r}}$$

Where $r_{\text{s}}=\dfrac{2GM}{c^2}$ is the radius of the event horizon. Accordingly

$$\dfrac{\Phi}{c^2}=1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{r_{\text{s}}}{r}}}$$

Note that even if your solution $(1)$ were correct, $\Phi(r)$ would still make $m=0$ at the event horizon $r=r_{\text{s}}$.

Comment: That is fudge. Lifting a 1Kg mass 1 metre m*dPhi = 9.82  while Phi*dm = 6.833*10^-9 and is a second order  term which under the rules of differential calculus should be neglected.

Comment: @BruceHarvey It's not a second order ($\ne\text{d}^2$) and you know it. The Earth gravity is just a Newtonian limit. You can't neglect in a stronger field, but even if you do, it wouldn't remove the horizon. Read the last sentence in the answer.

Comment: What you quote is the differential of E = m*Phi which gives dE = m*dPhi +Phi * dm and that makes your fudge seem plausible. but this is m*dPhi which is quite different. In ant course on calculus

Comment: In any course on calculus, this equation of exponential decay is the simplest example of the simplest type of differential equation, the separable variable DE and it applies to many situations in nature and physics such as the voyage of a capacitor discharging through a resistor.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the result is similar showing the same behavior - the mass-energy is reduced to zero at the horizon, so nothing crosses it. I have upvoted your question, because I agree that these is no singularity. A black hole is a mere result of energy conservation.