# QED: basic process which violates energy-momentum conservation

Tags: particle-physics, photons, momentum, conservation-laws, quantum-electrodynamics

Why is the following process not possible?

[image: process]

My book says it's because it violate energy and momentum conservation. Can someone 
explain me explicitly why? Why couldn't an energetic electron not radiate an photon and 
continue to propagate with a smaller momentum?

Comment: Put initial electron in the rest $(m,0,0,0)$. The emission photon is $(E,0,0,E)$. The electron after emitting photon is $(m−E,0,0,−E)$. By $p^2=m^2$, we have $(m−E)^2−E^2=m^2$ thus $−2mE=0$, which is not possible.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12488/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13513/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22916/2451 , and links therein.

Comment: @user26143: can you make that an answer. Comments are transient things and can disappear, but an answer will remain for future generations of budding physicists :-)

Comment: @John Rennie Surely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the initial electron in rest, the four momentum is $(m,0,0,0)$. The emission photon is $(E,0,0,E)$. The electron after emitting photon is $(m−E,0,0,−E)$. By $p^2=m^2$, we have $(m−E)^2−E^2=m^2$ thus $−2mE=0$, which is not possible.