# In QED, why is the $e^- + e^+\leftrightarrow\gamma$ process forbidden on-shell?

Tags: photons, momentum, conservation-laws, quantum-electrodynamics, virtual-particles

QED has a vertex that couples a single photon to two fermions. This vertex describes the annihilation of an electron-positron pair into a photon. Why is this process forbidden for all three particles being on shell?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13513/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22916/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12488/2451

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(I henceforth assume $c= \hbar=1$.) It is forbidden by the *four-momentum conservation* law. Put yourself in the centre of mass reference frame of the couple of massive particles (electron and positron). There $P_{e\overline{e}} = (2E,\vec{0})$ with $E\geq m_e>0$. Just because four momentum is conserved, this four-momentum must be the same as the one of the photon: $P_\nu=(k,\vec{k})$. So $k=2E$ and $\vec{k}=\vec{0}$. Since, for the photon $k= |\vec{k}|$, the two conditions cannot hold simultaneously and four-momentum conservation is violated. At least one of the three particle must be *virtual*.

Comment: Can one also use [Furry's theorem](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~fionnf/qft/furry.pdf) here to show that the amplitude is zero?

Comment: No, Love Learning, one can't. Furry's theorem is only about the expectation of the product of currents - and one needs both creation of a current (the electron and the positron Dirac operator) as well as a photon. The "dynamical part" of the amplitude behind this forbidden process doesn't really vanish; it is purely the kinematical part - one that only depends on the momenta - that vanishes for reasons that Valter described.