# Why is $\gamma \to 2\gamma$ kinematically forbidden?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, particle-physics, photons, conservation-laws

I've seen it claimed in multiple places that a photon can't split into two because that would violate conservation of momentum, e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/203131/25750). It seems to me this is simply false. What gives?

Here is a counterexample:

$P_1 = (1,-1,0,0)$

$P_2 = P_3 = (-\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2, 0,0)$

That is, $P_1,P_2,P_3$ are three nonzero null vectors in Minkowski space such that $P_1 + P_2 + P_3 = 0$ (where the "time" coordinate is the leading coordinate).  So on the basis of conservation of momentum alone, it seems to me that $\gamma \to 2 \gamma$ is permissible.

**Question 1:** Is the above correct? That is, is $\gamma \to 2\gamma$ permissible on the grounds of momentum conservation alone?

**Question 2:** If so, then is it still the case that $\gamma \to 2 \gamma$ is kinematically forbidden? (presumably this would have something to do with helicities?)

**Question 3:** If not, what forbids $\gamma \to 2\gamma$?

**Question 4:** Did I misunderstand the linked argument, or is my counterexample really a counterexample to the claim there?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106349/discussion-on-question-by-tcamps-why-is-gamma-to-2-gamma-kinematically-forbi).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not strictly forbidden for a massless particle to split into two, but the "volume of available phase space" is zero. Remember that the rates for processes are computed by finding a so-called matrix element, and then integrating it over phase space. The allowed phase space here is of measure zero, because you have the additional constraint that the two final particles be exactly collinear.

More concretely, suppose we applied some regulator like a discrete lattice. Depending on how the regulator is set up, the rate for the process you cited may be nonzero, or exactly zero. But for a reasonable regulator, the rate should limit to zero as it is removed, by the argument above.

Comment: Thanks! But how does this qualitatively differ from the case of a massive particle? Don't we still have the same number of constraints being imposed, so that the portion of phase space we're exploring has the same dimensionality?

Comment: @tcamps For massive $1 \to 2$, after accounting for energy and momentum conservation, you have a 2-dimensional available phase space. (This is easiest to see in the center of mass frame, where it just represents the direction the first particle comes out in.) For massless $1 \to 2$ you have the additional collinear constraint, leaving a 0-dimensional phase space. (Note that there is no center of mass frame at all, in this case.)

Comment: But I don't see how colinearity is an "additional" constraint: it follows from the equations $P_1 + P_2 + P_3 = 0$ and $\eta_{\mu\nu} P_a^\mu P_a^\nu = 0$ just as the constraints in the massive case follow from $P_1 + P_2 + P_3 = 0$ and $\eta_{\mu\nu} P_a^\mu P_a^\nu = m_a$ -- it's the same number of equations in each case. Do some of the equations in the massive case fail to be independent? That seems weird -- I'd expect if there was an extra dependency in one case but not the other, that it would be in the massless case because it's less "generic"....

Comment: @tcamps It's probably best not to think about the kind of counting you get for linear equations, because the equations are nonlinear. For example, $r^2 = 1$ is "one constraint" in 3D space, yet somehow $r^2 = 0$ is "three constraints" despite being "only one equation". In the massive case the constraints are indeed redundant, but in the massless case something like $r^2 = 0$ happens.

Comment: If my dimension count below is correct (It smells a little fishy, though -- it comes out negative in $1+1$ dimensions), then in $2+1$ dimensions the dimensionality is actually the same for the massive and massless $2 \to 1$. This suggests that perhaps massless $1 \to 2$ processes might be possible in 2 spatial dimensions. I suppose the relativistic considerations are not actually applicable in condensed matter systems, but I wonder if massless $1 \to 2$ might happen in some processes confined to a surface?

Comment: @tcamps I don't believe that's correct, in 2D, the $1 \to 2$ massive phase space is 1D (free variable is the angle the particles come out) and the $1 \to 2$ massless phase space is 0D. It definitely is true that in 1D this kind of splitting can happen, though!

Answer (score 3):

I just want to compile here a curated list of all the things I've seen said about this question here on this site, both right and wrong. The only answer I find truly satisfactory is "Correct Answer 3", as given by knzhou above.

**Question:** Can a massless particle spontaneously split in two?

**Correct Answer 1:**(if the particle is a photon) *No, because this would violate conservation of angular momentum.* The photon must have helicity $\pm 1$ (for reasons I don't fully understand). There's no way to have 3 numbers, all of them $\pm 1$, add up to zero. Of course, this argument relies on the photon having spin 1.

**Correct Answer 2:**(if the particle is a photon) *No, by Furry's Theorem in QED*. This is a dynamical argument rather than a kinematic one.

**Correct Answer 3:**(for any massless particle) *Perhaps in some sense yes, but only with probability zero*. Consider 1 incoming particle with momentum $P_1$ and 2 outgoing particles with momenta $P_2,P_3$ and masses $m_1,m_2,m_3$, in $D+1$ dimensions. The momenta $P_a^\mu$ have $3(D+1)$ degrees of freedom. Conservation of momentum says that $P_1^\mu = P_2^\mu + P_3^\mu$, which is $D+1$ constraints. The mass constraint says that $\eta_{\mu\nu}P^\mu_a P^\nu_a = (m_a)^2$, 3 more constraints. These constraints are "generically" independent, as when $m_2 + m_3 < m_1$, so they result in an "expected dimension" of the phase space of allowed configurations of $3(D+1) - (D+1) - 3 = 2D-1$ (i.e. this is the actual dimension when $m_2 + m_3 < m_1$). But when $m_1 = m_2 = m_3 = 0$, the dimension of phase space drops to $D+1$ because of positivity considerations -- the $P_a$ must be null and collinear [1]. So the dimension has dropped by $2D-1 - (D+1) = D-2$. Thus when $D \geq 3$, the dimension is smaller than "expected". Now, any reasonable integral over this phase space will be integrating a quantity of dimension $2D-1$ (the "expected dimension"), but in the massless case with $D \geq 3$, the integration will only be over a space of dimension $D + 1 < 2D-1$, so it will come out zero. As the probability of such an event happening will always be calculated by such an integral, the probability will always be zero.

**Marginally Correct Answer 4:**(if the particle is a photon) *No; this is not observed experimentally*. This is maybe an answer, though not an explanation. Even as an answer, it's marginal, because to be a serious answer, one would need to do some theoretical analysis to figure out where one should look to find such a strange effect and then actually search for it. Maybe it turns out to be as simple as looking at the lamp next to me and observing that its light stays yellow rather than becoming infrared as it cross the room -- but maybe not -- it depends on the theoretical analysis. This begs the question -- what goes into such an analysis?

**Possibly Correct Answer 5:**(for any massless particle) *No; for any "decay" process there must be a nonzero drop in total invariant mass from the incoming particles to the outgoing ones.* I'm not quite sure whether this answer is correct -- certainly *some* physical processes occurring in nature lead to a *gain* of invariant mass -- witness the existence of elements heavier than iron! So it seems this argument hinges on what exactly a "decay" is, and whether the hypothetical $\gamma \to 2\gamma$ would count as a "decay".  At any rate, this argument doesn't seem "kinematical" to me, because kinematics is always time-reversible, and this argument rests on a fundamentally non-time-reversible premise.

**Incorrect Answer 1:**(for any massless particle) *The momenta given in the counterexample above don't represent massless particles because their speed is not 1.* In fact, the speed of $(\frac 1 2, -\frac 1 2, 0, 0)$ is $\frac{\frac 1 2}{\frac 1 2} = 1$. Remember that unlike massive particles, there is no canonical normalization for the 4-momentum vector of a massless particle.

**Incorrect Answer 2:**(for any massless particle) *No; the momenta given in the counterexample above don't "really" represent 3 distinct particles.* In fact they do -- there's a different between two photons of energy $\frac 1 2$ and one photon of energy $1$. If that doesn't convince you, I hope you sort yourself out eventually, but you can also trivially modify the counterexample to have $P_2 = (-\frac 1 3, \frac 1 3, 0,0)$ and $P_3 = (-\frac 2 3, \frac 2 3, 0, 0)$.

**Incorrect Answer 3:**(for any massless particle) *No, because we could pass to a reference frame where $P_2$ and $P_3$ are going in opposite directions; this would put $P_1$ at rest, which is impossible because it is massless.* This argument overlooks the possibility of $P_1,P_2,P_3$ being collinear, which as we've seen is perfectly consistent with momentum conservation.

**Incorrect Answer 4:**(for any massless particle) *No, because the Lorentz group is noncompact*. This argument was given as an answer to the linked question of which this one is a duplicate. This argument is not explicit enough to say what's wrong it, but the above counterexample shows it must be wrong.

---

[1] Let us carefully work out the analysis of Correct Answer 3 above. Choose coordinates where

$P_1 = (1,-1,0,\dots,0)$.

Write $P_2 = (P^0,P^1,P^2,\dots,P^D)$.

Then by momentum conservation ($P_1 = P_2 + P_3$) we have

$P_3 = (1-P^0,-1-P^1,-P^2,\dots,-P^D)$.

The mass constraints say that

$(1) \qquad 0 = \eta_{\mu\nu}P_2^\mu P_2^\nu = (P^0)^2 - (P^1)^2 - (P^2)^2 - \dots -(P^D)^2$ and

$(2) \qquad 0 = \eta_{\mu\nu}P_3^\mu P_3^\nu = (1-P^0)^2 - (-1-P^1)^2 - (P^2)^2 - \dots -(P^D)^2$.

Equating the two expressions, we obtain

$0 = -2P^0 - 2P^1$, i.e. $P^1 = -P^0$.

Therefore, from the first equation we have

$0 = (P^2)^2 + \dots + (P^D)^2$, which forces $P^2 = \cdots = P^D = 0$ because the $P^\mu$ are real.

So we find that $P_2,P_3$ are each scalar multiples of $P_1$. So in coordinate-independent language, the solutions to our equation come when the $P_a$ are collinear, null, and satisfy $P_1 = P_2 + P_3$. So the space of solutions is given by choosing

- the null vector $P_1$ (that's $D$ dimensions), plus
- a scalar $c$ such that $P_2 = cP_1$ (one more dimension)

(we then take $P_3 = (1-c)P_1$). So the space of solutions has dimension $D+1$. The "dimension deficit" is

$(\text{"expected dimension"}) - (\text{actual dimension}) = (2D-1) - (D+1) = D-2$.

For those keeping track of home, what has happened is that in this case we effectively get the $D-1$ additional constraints $P^\mu = 0$ for $\mu \geq 2$, but one dimension of degeneracy has also crept into the system of constraints, which is why we end up with a "dimension deficit" of $D-2$. In fact, when $D = 1$, the positivity considerations are trivial and it's only the degeneracy that matters -- in this case we end up with a *larger* phase space than expected!

Comment: As indicated by knzhou in the comments which have been moved to chat above, Correct Answer #3 generalizes to show that for any number $N$, if $P_0 = P_1 + \dots + P_N$ are null vectors with positive energy, then the $P_a$ are all collinear. For if $P_1,P_2$, say, are not collinear, then $P_1+P_2$ is timelike. Then by convexity, the sum of $P_1 + P_2$ with any nonspacelike, positive-energy vector is timelike. In particular, $P_0$ is timelike, a contradiction. Then a similar dimension count will show that a massless particle can never directly decay into massless particles.

Answer (score 0):

It is not momentum conservation that forbids a zero mass particle to decay to two particles. It is the definition of "four vector", it's algebra,  and it's "length", the invariant mass, the definition of inertial frames.

Two particles will have an invariant mass  whereas the incoming particle has mass zero. The "length" of the four vectors is invariant between inertial frames by construction of the Lorentz transformation.

For zero mass decaying particles, in the collinear case in the lab,  at  the center of mass of the two massless particles,  momentum conservation enters,  they would have to be  in opposite directions, which gives an invariant mass.

Your four vectors are not consistent for a decay, they are random four vectors describing zero mass  particles that can add up to a zero mass four vector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand. Could you spell things out with some equations?

Comment: In particular, you claim that the two outgoing two particles will have an invariant mass, but it seems to me that in the counterexample I gave -- where the momenta of the outgoing particles are $Q_2 = Q_3 = (\frac 1 2, -\frac 1 2, 0,0)$ -- the total invariant mass is zero. That is, we have $\sqrt{\eta_{\mu\nu} Q_2^\mu Q_2^\nu} + \sqrt{\eta_{\mu\nu} Q_3^\mu Q_3^\nu} = 0 + 0 = 0$. In other words, the invariant mass, or "length", of a null vector is (by definition) zero.

Comment: Yes, that is why it is zero probability in the center of mass of the two outgoing photons. See the algebra of four vectors here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html . two four vectors that have an angle always have an invariant mass larger than zero., and in the center of mass have to have equal and opposite momentum.

Comment: If the mass is zero, as in your example, there is no center of mass as zero mass  particles always travel with velocity c.  So it is not a decay..

Comment: Seems to me then it is not a decay, but a break up of the incoming fourvector into arbitrary parts, that can never be observed of measured.

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow, but it's precisely the point of the example that the angle between the two 4-vectors $Q_2,Q_3$ is zero, so the argument that there should exist a "center of mass" frame doesn't apply -- this is discussed in "Incorrect Answer 3" in my CW answer. Your last comment sounds like "Incorrect Answer 2", as raised by Zorawar in the comments above. As I pointed out (and knzhou agreed), this is incorrect because  there _is_ a difference between 2 red photons and 1 blue photon.

Comment: yes , knzhou is correct. Since we have not observed this (monochromatic beams stay monochromatic), one is left with the kinematics of decay, which imposes the mass of the incoming to be larger than the added masses of the outgoing.(avoiding center of mass arguments)

Comment: It seems to me that the requirement for the mass afterwards to be less than the mass before is a _dynamical_ requirement rather than a kinematic one -- I agree that if the mass afterward is _greater_ than the mass before, then the process will not happen spontaneously. But I'm talking about a reversible process -- a massless particle spontaneously transforming into two massless particles with collinear 4-momenta can equally be viewed (via time-reversal) as two collinear massless particles merging into one. It seems to me that no _kinematical_ consideration forbids this.

Comment: well, then call it the "law" of decay, we do not observe changes in frequency of monochromatic light,. It is only the $m_1>m_2+m_3$, the $=$ is not allowed. either way: two collinear photons do not add to one with higher energy. (laser light would behave differently)

Comment: good night, it is my bedtime

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I've updated my CW answer to reflect some of your arguments to the best of my understanding. Could you clarify this "law of decay"? I'm sure we agree it's possible under certain conditions for two nuclei to to collide and merge with a resultant _increase_ in total invariant mass (e.g. any element heavier than iron must have been created this way). So presumably such a process doesn't count as a "decay". But it's still _possible_ (and happens in nature!). But then, what is a "decay", and why is this notion relevant to the question at hand?

Comment: Decays have been observed and studied and fitted with the rule above, without the equal  If photons would decay this way, there would be no beam of laser light everything would turn to infrared and disappear, since in this picture, of the =, the created photon is metastable . One could study your hypothesis mathematically by assuming a very small mass for the photon decaying to two massless particles , and take the limit of the photon mass going to zero. The center of mass argument would hold up to the actual zero, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106345/discussion-between-tcamps-and-anna-v).