# Is there any interpretation where GR and QM can be compatible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, epr-experiment

In [this article](https://einstein.stanford.edu/content/relativity/a11758.html) <sup>[1]</sup> , Dr. Sten Odenwald claimed that,

> **Quantum mechanics is incompatible with general relativity because in quantum field theory, forces act locally through the exchange of well-defined quanta**.

Is there any hypothesis where both of them can be compatible?

---

<sup>[1] - https://einstein.stanford.edu/content/relativity/a11758.html</sup>

Comment: Not an interpretation, but string theories are quantum theories and are candidates where gravity can be quantized .see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/how-does-classical-gr-concept-of-space-time-emerge-from-string-theory

Comment: I think he's just wrong. QFT is a theory of continuous fields in which discrete quanta are an emergent phenomenon, and the virtual particles exchanged in Feynman diagrams are not well-defined quanta at all. I see several other errors on the site, like [this answer](https://einstein.stanford.edu/content/relativity/a11278.html) where he says that gravity is the only nonlinear force, and [this one](https://einstein.stanford.edu/content/relativity/a10978.html) where he says the visible universe is 14 Gly across. That's just in the first 30 questions, I didn't look through all 205.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't agree with that quote. There is no problem with treating GR as a local effective quantum field theory, with gravitons being the quanta of the gravitational field (at least on a static background), below some scale.

The issue is not really about interpretation, it is more technical. We know how to quantize an effective field theory  when the energy of processes being considered is less than the *cutoff scale*. In the case of gravity, the cutoff scale is the *Planck energy*, $E_p = \sqrt{\hbar c^3/G} \approx 2 \times 10^9\ {\rm J}$. For processes below this energy, there is no problem thinking of Einstein's equations as describing a local quantum field theory of the gravitational field. Above this energy, we don't know how to treat the theory quantum mechanically. There are various proposals, some examples and roughly speaking how they try to solve the problem:

- String theory replaces the spacetime metric and quantum fields describing elementary particles with new degrees of freedom. In some limits, these degrees of freedom are described by strings propagating in 10 spacetime dimensions. In other situations, this same theory describes other objects like branes or reduces to a theory of supergravity. The main issue string theory has is connecting to observations. That's true of all quantum gravity approaches, but since string theory introduces some new elements (extra dimensions, additional unobserved light fields, multiple vacuaa), one challenge is explaining what set of ingredients actually reproduces our world. Additionally, no one knows how to formulate string theory (or "M-theory") precisely in a non-perturbative way, outside of the special case of asymptotically Anti de Sitter spacetimes.
- Loop quantum gravity keeps Einstein's equations, but uses a different set of degrees of freedom besides the metric and changes the methods we use to quantize a theory. A major challenge for loop quantum gravity is to show that in an appropriate limit, it reduces to classical GR.
- Asymptotic safety proposes that Einstein's equations and the fundamental metric degrees of freedom can be quantized directly, and we "simply" have to learn how to quantize the theory when we can no longer use perturbation theory. More technically, the proposal is that the renormalization group for gravity has a non-trivial UV fixed point. A major issue here is showing that this UV fixed point actually exists (and it is not at all clear that it does).

It is worth noting that the holographic principle seems to imply that quantum gravity should have a degree of "non-localness" to it, which is not present in quantum theory. This is perhaps a reason to be skeptical of the asymptotic safety scenario.

Comment: The moment you start quantizing GR, it is no longer GR.

Comment: @TimRias What does that mean?

Comment: @Avantgarde One point of view is that GR is the mathematical framework where gravity is defined as curvature in spacetime and the metric is related to the stress-energy tensor via Einstein's equations. Then GR is a classical theory, and if you quantize the metric then by definition you are no longer talking about GR. I tend to take a different point of view that all physics is really quantum mechanical (as far as we know), and I use "GR" as shorthand for the Einstein-Hilbert action even if treated quantum mechanically. IMO so long as everyone is clear what they mean, it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Is electromagnetism no longer electromagnetism if you start quantizing it?

Comment: @Avantgarde That would be my point of view :)

Comment: What does it become, then?

Comment: @Avantgarde No, sorry, I meant -- the point you are making that electromagnetism is electromagnetism even if you quantize it, is also my point of view. That's why I said I am ok with using "GR" to refer to a quantum theory in my comment. I was just trying to explain where Tim is probably coming from.

Comment: @Avantgarde once you quantize electromagnetism it gets a new name: quantum electrodynamics (QED). A priori, it is not clear that general relativity needs to be quantized, e.g. maybe the RHS of the Einstein equation is given by the expectation value of the energy momentum tensor. (If you try to make this self-consistent you still end up with trouble).

Comment: @TimRias You can call things by different names. It does not change the fact that quantum mechanics is a fact of our universe. GR is no different. It is a classical theory as usually studied, but it can be used to give concrete predictions (yet to be observed) at the quantum level. Electromagnetism is a phenomenon, not a theory, and so it doesn't get a new name when you quantize it. GR and quantum mechanics are perfectly consistent at low energies. The real problem is the high energy behavior of gravitational interaction.

Comment: @Avantgarde At this point it is not "a fact" that gravity is quantized. I would be surprised if it isn't, but it is certainly not a fact. Any predictions based on perturbative quantum gravity, at this point are conjecture, not predictions of GR. E.g. if there is no graviton Hawking radiation this would not falsify GR.

Comment: @TimRias Quantum mechanics is a fact, and has been observed in every interaction except gravity. It is natural to expect that gravity also has a quantum description. Detecting individual gravitons is practically difficult problem, but we have already observed large, coherent collections of them in the form of gravitational waves. Hawking radiation is a problem that comes much later. Perturbative GR (not quantum gravity) is a perfectly consistent effective (quantum) field theory at low energies. E.g. Quantum corrections to the Newtonian potential have been calculated, but are too small to detec

Comment: Just a note that detecting gravitons might be more than a practically difficult problem: https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/poincare2012.pdf Not to say that the effective field theory of gravity doesn't work (I think it probably does), but it's an interesting thing to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is that there are no nontrivial diffeomorphism-invariant local observables for general relativity. C.G. Torre's "Gravitational Observables and Local Symmetries" ([arXiv:gr-qc/9306030](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9306030)) proved this for the vacuum, and adding matter doesn't help things.

We can try to construct a class of observables by considering integrals over spacetime of scalar functions, but this family of observables do not posses a *local* interpretation. The scalar must commute with the generators of the diffeomorphism constraints. For a given scalar field $\phi(x)$, the diffeomorphism group acts as $\partial_{\mu}\phi(x)$ which vanishes if and only if $\phi(x)=\phi_{0}$ is a constant. Torre has shown general relativistic observables must include an infinite number of derivatives and hence are very nonlocal.

Quantum theory doesn't handle nonlocal obserables very well, and I believe this is what the OP's quote references: since there are Dirac observables for General Relativity, it doesn't play into quantum theory very well.

Loop Quantum Gravity uses holonomies to construct its observables, and holonomies are nonlocal. String theory has a similar implicit use of nonlocality.