# Can a black hole actually grow, from the point of view of a distant observer?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time, observers, event-horizon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Black hole formation as seen by a distant observer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47669/black-hole-formation-as-seen-by-a-distant-observer)

I've read in several places that from the PoV of a distant observer it will take an infinite amount of time for new matter to fall past the event horizon into a black hole, due to time dilation effects.

This seems to imply that once a black hole is formed, its mass cannot actually grow any further as considered by most observers in the universe. Is that right?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47669/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi roblev, I'd say that the question linked by Qmechanic is an exact duplicate.  If there's anything that you feel isn't covered by that question, you need to specifically highlight it here otherwise I think this will get closed.

Comment: ok sorry I did look for duplicate but missed this one

Comment: @dmckee I do not see it as a duplicate because it asks about growth rather than formation.