# Time dilation at event horizon and outside universe

Tags: black-holes, time-dilation, event-horizon

From what I know, time dilation is almost infinite at the event horizon of a black hole. Therefore, infinite time should pass from an uninfluenced observer’s reference frame compared to the reference frame at the event horizon.

If the above statement is true, does this imply all mass that a black hole will (or has) consumed is approaching rapidly to a black hole’s event horizon simultaneously, since infinite time is passed outside the black hole’s reference frame?

Comment: No. The mass is there prior to its formation, but must compress to a certain size (look up _Schwarzschild radius_) to become a black hole. This can happen when a massive star has used up its nuclear fuel and becomes unstable collapsing under gravity into a small region. The mass (most of it) that once made up the star is now confined within the black hole event horizon. More mass from other sources can fall into the black hole, and this happens in _finite_ (proper) time.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21319/123208

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47669/123208