# if somehow we could survive in black hole would we survive the end of universe as time inside black hole would stop and would be infinite?

Tags: black-holes

as time goes on slowing with increase in mass. how can black hole ever form in finite time. is infinite time has different meaning for different observer. if so would the event of universe dying be different for different observer?

Comment: See also this http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5031/37364

Comment: so does this mean going inside the event horizon is to go in time for end of universe? due to infinte slowing of time? @mmesser314

Comment: From the point of view of a person falling in, nothing special happens at the event horizon. You see light continue to see light from the outside universe. You do not see the end of the universe before you hit the singularity.