# Black Hole Formation Physics

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, reference-frames, observers, event-horizon

Considering only Black Holes that form due to gravitational collapse since the big-bang, wouldn't it be true that that have not (in our reference frame), in fact, formed a singularity or even much of the interior of the black hole given GR time dilation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can black holes form in a finite amount of time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5031/)