# Can matter actually cross the event horizon effectively falling into a Black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, reference-frames, observers, event-horizon

The answers I have seen do not take into effect the growth of the radius of the event horizon as significant amounts of matter get close to the existing event horizon. I would have expected that rather than it taking forever to cross a fixed event horizon, reality would be that a growing spherical event horizon would engulf the object falling into the blackhole.

Comment: How is the event horizon supposed to "grow" if nothing ever falls past it? Related/possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82678/50583 and its linked questions

Comment: This seems to start from a misconception and then propose a way to poke a hole in the misconception, which wasn't valid in the first place. It is not true that matter *can't* cross the event horizon. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5031/can-black-holes-form-in-a-finite-amount-of-time

Comment: The object is only "frozen" at the horizon in _coordinate_ time.  It most definitely crosses the horizon in finite _proper_ time.  This is one reason not to entrust physics to a particular coordinate chart.  Growth of the event horizon is not usually taken into effect because the Schwartzschild metric does not allow it - it is static!

Comment: @ACuriousMind A thin shell of the same mass $M$ as the BH collapses to the EH, but doesn't cross it yet. Would the horizon radius not increase to $2M$? Whether or not you believe that the growing horizon pushes nearby objects off, either way you have to admit that the horizon grows before the infalling matter crosses it.