# Nothing can ever go through the event horizon of a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

Nothing can ever fall into a black hole, even from the perspective of something in the process of falling through (a process I am arguing can never be completed.) Here's my argument.

As seen from the outside, nothing can enter a black hole because it becomes infinitely slow before it reaches the event horizon. Now suppose it takes a googol years (as measured from outside) for a particular black hole to dissipate. Then the black hole dissipates before anything can enter into it. So from the perspective of something falling toward the event horizon, they will experience the black hole dissipating and the event horizon vanishing before they can ever enter it.

Can you tell me what's wrong with this argument?

Comment: *As seen from the outside, nothing can enter a black hole because it becomes infinitely slow before it reaches the event horizon* Is this true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can black holes form in a finite amount of time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5031/)