# Does a geodesic exist that will take someone across the event horizon?

Tags: black-holes, observers, event-horizon, estimation, causality

I saw the movie "Interstellar" a few years back, and was amazed that Cooper was able to fall from 1 AU into a black hole before his daughter turned 110. Intuitively, I would think that there are no paths in our spacetime that cross over the event horizon.

Does a geodesic exist that can take one from normal space to the other side of an event horizon before the end of time?

Comment: There are no time-like paths, geodesic or otherwise, that cross the event horizon in a finite time as measured by an external observer. How the film gets around this is not a topic for the Physics SE. My recollection is that it involved humans from the future working through a  five dimensional space.

Comment: I assume the same applies to light-like paths. Correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have said time-like or light-like paths,

Comment: *before the end of time?* Whose time? There are geodesics that cross the horizon and reach the singularity in finite proper time (i.e., as measured by the infalling person). So, if you fall in, are you more concerned about what you’ll experience (death) or what distant observers will see (something similar to watching paint dry)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can black holes form in a finite amount of time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5031/)

Comment: @Ghoster in this case it involved an observer (Joseph Cooper) who has fallen through the horizon communicating with an observer (his daughter) who is outside the horizon, so it is reasonably well defined. Cooper would have to leave his daughter, fall through the horizon then be able to send a message to his daughter in a finite time as measured by his daughter.

Comment: @TimRias Probably because it's from a fictional movie, but I agree it's not a good reason since they made some effort to be accurate in Interstellar. What about my closure reason though – a duplicate? Variations of "Can anything really cross the horizon in a finite time?" have been asked many times. I'd vote to close again but it's not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a geodesic exist that can take one from normal space to the other side of an event horizon before the end of time?

### TLDR answer

Yes.

### More complete answer

There are geodesics that do cross the event horizon. Both the geodesics themselves and the horizon are coordinate independent features of the spacetime, so this statement is fully coordinate independent. These geodesics include timelike, null, and spacelike geodesics. In principle, Cooper could follow a timelike geodesic across the horizon, so all further discussion of geodesics will specifically assume timelike geodesics.

In the Schwarzschild spacetime all timelike geodesics pass through the event horizon and then go to the singularity. So that clearly answers the question "Does a geodesic exist that can take one from normal space to the other side of an event horizon" in the affirmative, consistent with the TLDR answer.

The only tricky or complicated part is the final part of the question "before the end of time". That phrase is ambiguous, so there are multiple ways to interpret it. Here is a list of ways to interpret that phrase and the consequence to the TLDR answer.

"before the end of time" could mean:

1. Before the end of proper time along the geodesic. This is my preferred interpretation because proper time is coordinate independent, so this is the meaning that makes the whole question one about the physics rather than about some arbitrary choice of coordinates. In this case, **the answer is Yes**. Proper time ends as the geodesic approaches the singularity, and the crossing of the event horizon is an earlier event.
2. Before the end of coordinate time in $X$ coordinates where $X \in \{\text{Schwarzschild, isotropic, ...} \}$. Since this is a coordinate time this will only be true when using $X$ coordinates. The $X$ coordinates do not cover the region of spacetime containing the event horizon, so the $t$ coordinate ends before the horizon. Therefore, in this case **the answer is No**. The event where the geodesic crosses the horizon is after the end of $X$ coordinate time.
3. Before the end of coordinate time in $X$ coordinates where $X \in \{\text{Kruskal–Szekeres, Lemaître, Gullstrand–Painlevé, ...} \}$. Since this is a coordinate time this will only be true when using $X$ coordinates. The $t$ coordinate in $X$ coordinates is finite at the horizon, so the horizon is in the region covered by these coordinates. Therefore, in this case **the answer is Yes**. The event where the geodesic crosses the horizon is before the end of $X$ coordinate time.
4. Before the end of coordinate time in $X$ coordinates where $X \in \{\text{Eddington-Finkelstein, ...} \}$. This will only be true when using $X$ coordinates. There is no coordinate time in $X$ coordinates. None of the coordinates are timelike, there are only spacelike and null coordinates. The coordinate chart covers the event horizon, so the event where the geodesic crosses the horizon has perfectly valid and finite coordinates in $X$ coordinates. But none of those coordinates are "time". Therefore, in this case **the answer is undefined**. There is no time so there is no end of time so there is no way to compare the perfectly valid event of crossing horizon with the end of time to determine if it was before or after.