# When a neutral star with a magnetic field collapses to form a black hole, what happens to the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes

By the no-hair theorem, black holes are only characterized by mass, charge and angular momentum.  If the star is neutral, the black hole will have only mass and angular momentum - and therefore it cannot have a magnetic dipole field.  Where did it go?

---

These three questions are similar but I think the answers will be different for each one:

> [What happens to an embedded magnetic field when a black hole is formed from rotating charged dust?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39161/what-happens-to-an-embedded-magnetic-field-when-a-black-hole-is-formed-from-rota)
>   It seems to me a rotating charged black hole must have a dipole
>   magnetic field. But the strength of the dipole field seems like an
>   extra parameter that black holes are forbidden by the no-hair theorem.
>
> [If a magnetic monopole falls into a schwarzchild black hole, what happens to the magnetic field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39174/if-a-magnetic-monopole-falls-into-a-schwarzchild-black-hole-what-happens-to-the)
>   Here there would be only radial magnetic field lines leaving from the
>   event horizon to infinity.  So if magnetic charge is counted as charge
>   this should be no problem.  But if the black hole were rotating
>   wouldn't that produce an electric dipole field?
>
> [When a neutral star with a magnetic field collapses to form a black hole, what happens to the magnetic field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39173/when-a-neutral-star-with-a-magnetic-field-collapses-to-form-a-black-hole-what-h)
>   Here there is no charge so how can there be a magnetic field
>   associated with a black hole? That would definitely violate the
>   no-hair theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a test of the collapse of a magnetized neutron star (case 3) in this preprint: http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1208.3487.

Here is some of the text and figures from that paper that describe how the magnetic field is expelled:

> 3. Magnetized Collapse to a Black Hole
>
> Our final and most comprehensive test is represented by the collapse
>   to a BH of a magnetized nonrotating star. This is more than a purely
>   numerical test as it simulates a process that is expected to take
>   place in astrophysically realistic conditions, such as those
>   accompanying the merger of a binary system of magnetized neutron stars
>   [26, 27], or of an accreting magnetized neutron star. The interest in
>   this process lays in that the collapse will not only be a strong
>   source of gravitational waves, but also of electromagnetic radiation,
>   that could be potentially detectable (either directly or as processed
>   signal). The magnetized plasma and electromagnetic fields that
>   surround the star, in fact, will react dynamically to the rapidly
>   changing and strong gravitational fields of the collapsing star and
>   respond by emitting electromagnetic radiation. Of course, no
>   gravitational waves can be emitted in the case considered here of a
>   nonrotating star, but we can nevertheless explore with unprecedented
>   accuracy the electromagnetic emission and assess, in particular, the
>   efficiency of the process and thus estimate how much of the available
>   binding energy is actually radiated in electromagnetic waves. Our
>   setup also allows us to investigate the dynamics of the
>   electromagnetic fields once a BH is formed and hence to assess the
>   validity of the no-hair theorem, which predicts the exponential decay
>   of any electromagnetic field in terms of Quasi Normal Mode (QNM)
>   emission from the BH.
>
> ...
>
> As the collapse proceeds, the restmass density in the center and the
>   curvature of the spacetime increase until an appararent horizon is
>   found at t = 0.57 ms and is marked with a thin red line in Fig. 12. 
>   As the stellar matter is accreted onto the BH (the rest-mass outside
>   the horizon $M_{b, out} = 0$ is zero by $t \geq 0.62$ ms), the external magnetic
>   field which was anchored on the stellar surface becomes disconnected,
>   forming closed magneticfield loopswhich carry away the electromagnetic
>   energy in the form of dipolar radiation. This process, which has been
>   described through a simplified non-relativistic analytical model in
>   Ref. [52], predicts the presence of regions where |E| > |B| as the
>   toroidal electric field propagates outwards as a wave. This process
>   can be observed very clearly in Fig. 13, which displays the same three
>   bottom panels of Fig. 12 on a smaller scale of only 15 km to highlight
>   the dynamics near the horizon. In particular, it is now very clear
>   that a closed set of magnetic field lines is built just outside the
>   horizon at t = 1.0 ms, that is radiated away. Note also that our
>   choice of gauges (which are the same used in [61]) allows us to model
>   without problems also the solution inside the apparent horizon. While
>   the left panel of Fig. 13 shows thatmost of the rest-mass is
>   dissipated away already by t = 0.65 ms (see discussion in [62] about
>   why this happens), some of the matter remains on the grid near the
>   singularity, anchoring there the magnetic field which slowly evolves
>   as shown in the middle and right panels.
>   [image: Magnetic Star Collapse]

[image: Closeup Magnetic Star Collapse]

Comment: very nice, but this doesn't not seem to explain how a potential monopole field would disconnect,  without some topological string attached to the event horizon the magnetic field must be divergence less outside