# Why don't black holes have magnetic hair?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to an embedded magnetic field when a black hole is formed from rotating charged dust?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39161/what-happens-to-an-embedded-magnetic-field-when-a-black-hole-is-formed-from-rota)

It is well stablished that the only hair a black hole can have is:

1. mass
2. angular momentum
3. electric charge

But I can't help but wonder about the last two: a rotating charge will generate a current, that will generate a magnetic field. So, how is it even possible that the electric charge and angular momentum together will not generate a magnetic field?

Since we are forbidden by the event horizon to measure any distribution of the electric charge, it means that the charge must be evenly distributed over the event horizon, and for sure we know that a rotating charged shell will generate a magnetic field

What is amiss in this picture?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to an embedded magnetic field when a black hole is formed from rotating charged dust?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39161/what-happens-to-an-embedded-magnetic-field-when-a-black-hole-is-formed-from-rota).  Also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39173/when-a-neutral-star-with-a-magnetic-field-collapses-to-form-a-black-hole-what-h

Comment: In addition to the excellent answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39161/what-happens-to-an-embedded-magnetic-field-when-a-black-hole-is-formed-from-rota , I personally verified this prediction and interpretation of the no hair theorem with Prof Lenny Susskind of Stanford.

Comment: thanks for the links to these excellent answers, i didn't found them after looking for a bit