# Electric and magnetic field in a black hole

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes, astrophysics

I have many questions about this topic:

1. Does the electric field of a charged black hole look like [this](http://www.greatians.com/physics/universe/black%20hole.htm)? I mean how can it have an electric field if nothing can escape from a black hole, and what is more, why would it be identical to a charged particle's field?
2. In [this Phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39161/), what is the origin of the magnetic field of the black hole, can I say that because it's rotating and has a charge it produces a current and therefore a magnetic field?
3. What is the origin of the magnetic field [here](http://phys.org/news/2014-06-surprisingly-strong-magnetic-fields-black.html)? Is it created because of the disk of infalling matter, or does the black hole necessarly need to be charged and spinning around?

Comment: Light can escape a non-rotating black hole, but only along radial lines but will be infinitely red-shifted.  However, black holes rotate so this idea is a little too simplified.  Regardless, typically one assumes that the matter accreting into the hole is ionized and thus produces electromagnetic fields.  So think of a charged spinning disk and the fields that would produce (for a very simplified model).