# Can an electric field be detected around a large black hole?

Tags: black-holes, electric-fields, event-horizon

There is an existing question [Why can an electric field escape from a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235253/2451) which has a complex answer, not accessible to the layman.

The point of this new question is that the electromagnetic field is mediated by photons. Yet photons emitted at the surface of a black hole (of a large enough mass) will not be able to escape beyond the event horizon.

Would a large black hole have no measurable electric field beyond its event horizon, even if it carried a high charge at its surface?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detection of the Electric Charge of a Black Hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12169/)

Comment: Also see http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/black_gravity.html

Comment: Reissner-Nordström and Kerr-Newman black holes have detectable-in-principle electric (and, for K-N, magnetic) fields outside the horizon. Neither has any charge *at* the horizon. However, actual black holes are probably almost neutral.