# How can a black hole have a charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, electric-fields, charge

Under current particle theory, the four fundamental forces use a force-carrying particle. The particle for electromagnetism is the photon.  By definition a black hole is a mass from which light can not escape, so how does the photon get out of the black hole to carry the charge force?

Comment: Due to time dilation, observers outside the black hole would never see the charge cross the event horizon. So the total charge would effectively be spread over the surface. But once you cross the event horizon yourself, the total charge would obviously appear to come from deeper in the hole

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12169/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It's really not best to think of static fields in terms of force-carriers.  The photon field is a disturbance in the electromagnetic field, and the field of a black hole or any isolated static charge is a nice static charge best described in terms of the field.

Comment: 1. The gravitational force would not have a vector boson, but a tensor boson, but gravity isn't quantized yet. 2. The notion of how exactly these bosons "carry" the force is subtle, involves virtual particles, and has little to do with how the classical theories view charges and force fields (and GR is a classical theory).

Comment: @ACuriousMind 1. was my mistake in an edit, now undone