# If the photon is the force-carrier for the electromagnetic force, how does the electric charge of a black hole escape the event horizon?

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes, photons, event-horizon

When people speak of the electric charge of a black hole, do we actually mean it affects things outside of the event-horizon or is it just a property it has?

Comment: Related: [Why can an electric field escape from a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235253/) and [Why does the electric field escape a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166033/) and [How can a black hole have a charge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/182881/) and probably others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can an electric field escape from a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235253/)

Comment: More: [Detection of the electric charge of a black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12169/)

Comment: Also related: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/black_gravity.html

Comment: Thank you so much, tried searching for these questions but my limited physics-knowledge failed me.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer the question in the body of your post and not in the original subject line (on force carriers) which is a different subject.
.
from our reference frame safely outside the black hole, all the objects that fall into it never make it through the event horizon: they appear to get stuck there in a vanishingly thin layer just outside the EH. This includes electrical charges, which to us appear to reside just outside the EH and radiate their field lines outward into space just as if the black hole itself (inside the EH) were a point charge in space. So any net electric field that a black hole may possess is simply the sum of all the charge that fell onto its event horizon over its lifetime, plus whatever charge it originally had before it collapsed into a black hole.

Those charges radiate their field into space and would be detectable to us in the same way any other charged object would be.

Comment: This doesn’t explain “eternal” black hole solutions with charge.

Comment: you can do so in another answer. If it's better than mine I'll delete mine.

Comment: @G.Smith The charge of (non-existing) eternal black holes is also located at the horizon, as observed from outside. The (hypothetical) inner spacetime is in the causal future and has no effect on the outside.

Comment: @safesphere, thanks, will edit.

Comment: @safesphere, done.