# Virtual photons around a Reissner-Nordström black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, quantum-electrodynamics, virtual-particles, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Say we have a Reissner-Nordström charged black hole. There is a static electric field around it and far away it is that of a point charge. This poses a puzzle because signals cannot travel outside a black hole. According to [this Phys.SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12169/) and the [link](https://facultystaff.richmond.edu/~ebunn/ajpans/ajpans.html) contained therein,

- *Classically* we may say the Coulomb potential is sourced by infalling charged particles in the far past light cone of a test particle.
- *Quantum mechanically* the Coulomb potential comes from mediating virtual photons sourced by the infalling charged particles in the far past *and* the black hole itself. That is, according to the second link, virtual photons can cross a black hole event horizon.

> 1) Is this true? *("...the electromagnetic interaction between a test charge and the black hole is mediated by both horizon-crossing and non-horizon-crossing virtual photons.")*
>
> 2) What *can't* virtual photons do? Doesn't that violate causality? I know that virtual photons, in flat spacetime QFT, do not violate causality because we don't need to assume they exist; they can be considered a mathematical device requiring no physical interpretation. But causality bans interaction between a test particle and the inside of a black hole.

Answer (score 1):

This link (http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/black_gravity.html) offers a good answer. In particular,

1) Yes, it is true

2) There is really no difference between a virtual photon traveling violating locality in flat QFT and a virtual photon going outside a black hole. Both are instances of escaping its light cone.