# How do a black hole made from electrons produce EM field?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, electric-fields, charge

Imagine trillions upon trillions of electrons are squeezed into a tiny region of space creating a blackhole, how do this charged blackhole emit electromagnetic field? Hawking radiation do not count and assume no materials are falling in.

Comment: have you looked up this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charged_black_hole

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12169/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Coulomb electrostatic field (in a proper gauge) propagates instantaneously. So it escapes black hole without any problem.