# How can black holes have gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does gravity escape a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/937/how-does-gravity-escape-a-black-hole)

How can gravity get out of a black hole? If a black hole is so powerful that even light does not travel fast enough to get out, and gravity, or rather, gravitational waves, travel at the speed of light, how does gravity get out?

And please don't say that the black hole creates a "well" in space that other masses "slide" down. Such a well would be unstable and, if two black holes pass near each other, neither would be able to "slide" down the other since both are infinitely deep. These wells would make gravity selective.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/937/2451

Comment: Qmechanic beat me to the punch.

Comment: *"And please don't say that the black hole creates a "well" in space that other masses "slide" down."* Be aware that word picture like that are not (and never have been) the theory. The math is the theory and unless you understand the math it is foolish to make claims like *"if two black holes pass near each other, neither would be able to "slide" down the other since both are infinitely deep. These wells would make gravity selective."* because that is not what the math says.

Comment: Two passing black holes are well accommodated in the theory which makes specific predictions for that case and an effort is underway to observe the gravitational waves predicted by the theory.