# Nothing escapes BHs, gravitons mediate gravity, so why do BHs gravitate?

Tags: gravity, forces, black-holes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does gravity escape a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/937/how-does-gravity-escape-a-black-hole)

Nothing escapes black holes, gravitons mediate gravity, so why do black holes gravitate?

My question is, "where is the hole (no pun intended!) in the above understanding?"

Comment: Relevant Note: We do not yet have a generally accepted theory of quantum gravitation.

Comment: @DmitryBrant Thanks, I was unable to find that question. Should I delete this one?

Comment: @user16307  The link works fine for me and points to a duplicate question for which many answers were posted.  I would recommend this one be removed.

Comment: Sorry, there was a misunderstanding. "I was unable to find that question"... and that's why I made this one. But, when you (kindly) showed me the other question, I realised mine was redundant and so I asked if I should delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always virtual particles that "mediate" the interactions, not real ones. You imply real gravitons, not virtual ones; this is a hole in your reasoning.