# Graviton through the horizon and force felt outside a black hole

Tags: gravity, black-holes, event-horizon

Gravitational force is mediated by graviton exchange. If I am standing outside a black hole, I can of course feel the attracting force towards the black hole. This should correspond to gravitons mediated between the matter inside the horizon and myself; but then these gravitons should cross the horizon from the inside to the outside.

My question is: how is this paradox precisely solved?

I guess a starting point for an answer is that these gravitons are off-shell, much like in QED where photons exchanged between electrons that feel each other are virtual. But still, this confuses me a bit - is there some references explaining this in detail?

Comment: You can't think of gravitons with Black Holes, because that's naively putting a quantum theory in GR, which we don't know how to resolve yet.

Comment: @ChrisGerig: gravitons are appearing already at the semi-classical approximation of gravity, which is meaningful even if it is a non-renormalisable theory (think for example about Fermi theory - you still draw three level graphs and so on, although it is non-renormalisable). Of course in this case we are interested in gravitons seen as perturbation around a non-trivial solution of the equation of motion, but still, semi-classical approximation make sense.

Comment: Semi-classical gravity breaks down for black holes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does gravity escape a black hole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/937/)

Comment: In some special cases, it is clear that there is no paradox: For a fixed outside observer, there is nothing beyond the horizon, so there is no paradox.
For a free falling outside observer, he is a inertial observer, so he does not feel gravitation, so there is no paradox too.

Comment: @ChrisGerig: well, semi-classical approximation means that you consider quantum fluctuations at first order around a classical solution of the equations of motions. A particular case of this is when you expand around the vacuum, but you may well expand around other non-trivial solutions. This is done for example in non-abelian euclidean YM theory, where typically you compute progapators and so on in an instanton background.
JohnRennie: thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: No the point is that the theory isn't valid for large mass. Also this "paradox" has been asked many times on the Internet, you should be checking that out.