# If gravitational radiation (or anything) cannot escape a black hole, how can it produce redshift or curve spacetime?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, speed-of-light

There is an apparent paradox in a Black hole.
Keenan Pepper [wrote](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/975/2451):

> *Electromagnetic radiation cannot escape a black hole, because it travels at the speed of light. Similarly, gravitational radiation cannot escape a black hole either, because it too travels at the speed of light.*

If this is true, then evidently a BH cannot exert a pull at the centre of a Galaxy, neither it can suck off the energy out of light trying to excape from it , etc?

EDIT: *should I ask a new question about this*?
@John Rennie, saying that gravity is curvature, seems like **shifting the problem** (,like saying that electrostatic pull is the electric field). Relativity says that mass curves spacetime, but that supposes interaction. How can spacetime *know* that a BH is there, if it cannot communicate? a planet modifies surrounding spacetime in some way, and that , in its turn, affects bodies and light.
The question now becomes: **how does a BH acts on surrounding spacetime** to make it curve, since nothing can excape it, except Hawkings radiation?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting thought experiment disproving gravitons. But the existence of gravity waves has already been proven.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/937/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I misunderstood this question at first due to strange wording. It is a very intriguing question, rewording it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a logical flaw in the assumption: **gravitational radiation is not the cause of gravitational attraction**. The latter is due to **curvature of spacetime outside** the black hole. For a black hole to attract/exert redshift on something, nothing has to propagate from inside the event horizon. Gravitational waves (radiation) merely represent moving disturbances in spacetime, they are not what causes the force of gravity, just like a ray of light does not pull you towards its source electromagnetically.

Comment: I think my own confusion on this topic comes from my (presumably flawed) understanding that mass induces curvature and the graviton is the particle mediating the "hey space, I'm massive, so bend now" type of message. So if the gravitons can't get past the horizon the space outside can't possibly curve in response. Does anything at all mediate between massive objects and spacetime curvature? What exactly is the mechanism curving space?