# Gravitational boson violating relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

Currently doing a introductory degree level physics course, they were talking about how changes in gravity/gravitational field cause changes so quickly that if you assigned it the "graviton" said boson would have to be breaking the speed of limit in order for the changes to be possible.

My question, is there any research or current theory's that are at all successful in resolving this issue ?

Comment: *speed of limit* - Did you mean "speed of light"?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/937/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5456/2451 and links therein.