# If gravitons are particles, how do they escape BH gravity if nothing can?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes

1. If gravitons are particles, how do they escape BH gravity if nothing can?
2. So are the gravitons really particles or is there really just/only curvature of space-time?

Comment: Duplicate of [How does gravity escape a black hole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/937/50583)

Comment: If gravitons exist (a big if), they would be quanta of the gravitational field, i.e. they don't have to escape, they "are" what makes the black hole, in the first place.

Comment: To reopen this question (v2) please [ask only one question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6833/2451).