# Could gravity be a weak force because gravitons are absorbing gravitons before they reach a target rest mass?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, gluons

Could gravitons be similar to the gluons in the colour force? Can gravitons absorb other gravitons before they reach their target rest mass?

Comment: You say similar to gluons, but the strong force is quite strong since the residual strong force, the strong nuclear force, is able to overcome electromagnetic repulsion between protons in the nucleus.

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293873/do-gravitons-interact-with-each-other

Answer (score 4):

Classical general relativity has many well-known phenomena involving gravitational fields interacting with themselves, most dramatically the [geon solutions](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9610074) which describe gravitational radiation collapsing to a black hole.

Since classical general relativity has self-interacting gravity, it would make sense for there to be solutions where gravitons absorb and emit other gravitons in a full quantum gravitational theory, but this is unrelated to why one would expect gravity to be weak (as you said, gluons absorb and emit gluons, and no one  would characterize the strong force as "weak")

Comment: I meant to say that gravitons would not be absorbed by a target rest mass because other gravitons would get in their way and absorb them before they reached the target. Thanks for the information on  gravitational radiation.

Comment: All the forces have different strengths. Perhaps there is a new kind of particle that  carries a different kind of  charge for each force and this new particle absorbs force causing bosons with a different probability for each force thus weakening each force to a different extent.This would mean that photons for example carry a charge we haven't yet detected