# If gravitational waves travel at the speed of light, how can they escape black holes?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, speed-of-light, gravitational-waves

It is known that gravitational waves travel at the speed of light, and are themselves subject to lensing by gravity. My question is, how then do the waves escape the black hole they came from in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does gravity escape a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/937/)

Comment: @AdrianHoward Ah yes, I didn't see that when writing my question. I would be satisfied with a close as duplicate