# Why black holes curve spacetime using their mass and charge?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, curvature, mass-energy, event-horizon

We know, in a black hole, after the Schwarzchild radius, no information or particle can come out from inside.

We also know that, for interaction between charges or masses; exchange of some intermediate particle is necessary from the point of view of particle physics.

Then how exactly do black holes affect their spacetime outside schwarzchild radius? Outside the black hole, there should be no effect of the mass or charge inside, as no intermediate particle can exchange the Coulomb or some other interaction between two particles, one inside and one outside the black hole.

Comment: This is incorrect, the *externally* observable properties of a black hole are famously its mass, charge, and spin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem. See the answers to questions here like https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/937/how-does-gravity-escape-a-black-hole for how/why we can observe these properties.

Comment: "*Outside the black hole, there should be no effect of the mass or charge inside*" - This is correct. So nothing is inside. See the correct answers of dcgeorge and Lawrence B. Crowell in the duplicate link.