# How can black holes emit detectable magnetic fields and gravity if nothing can escape the event horizon?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, magnetic-fields, event-horizon, causality

How can black holes emit detectable magnetic fields and gravity if nothing can escape the event horizon?

Comment: Do you think the entire black hole is contained within its event horizon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does gravity escape a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/937/)