# Black Holes and Gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, speed-of-light, event-horizon

We know that nothing including light can escape the gravitational pull of black hole. Now special relativity says that nothing travels faster than speed of light.  Then how can effects of gravity due to the black hole be felt outside the black hole as nothing can escape black hole? This seems contradictory as anything is pulled inside the black hole due to gravity whereas nothing can escape a black hole.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/937/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Your question is based on a wrong assumption that the source of gravity is inside a black hole. See the correct answer by Charles in the duplicate. Nothing is inside. The source of gravity is the horizon. Looking at this differently, the horizon is a window to the future. Anything inside is in the future relative to us. Future doesn’t affect the present. A bomb exploding tomorrow cannot harm you today. Even if a source of gravity existed inside, it would produce no gravity outside, because from our perspective the “inside” (or anything in it) doesn’t exist yet (and never will).